# Imported struct from other package is undefined

Tags: go, struct

Here is my noobish problem. I have this struct in my `models/model.go`

```
    package models

    import (
      "time"
      "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"

    )

    type Horse struct {
        Id    bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
        Title       string
        Description string
        CreatedOn   time.Time
        Creator     string
        Visits  int
        Score       int

    }
```

And in my `controllers/crud.go` I'm trying to use `Horse` struct

```
package controllers

import (
  "html/template"
  "log"
  "net/http"
  "horseapp/models"
)
[...]
var horseStore = make(map[string]Horse) //This raises undefined error
```

But I get `undefined: Horse` when I `go install horseapp`.

What is wrong here and how to fix it?

Comment: Did you mean `models.Horse`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
var horseStore = make(map[string]models.Horse)
```

When accessing an identifier from another package you will always have to prefix it with the packages name and a dot: `package.Identifier`

Comment: You are right. Thanks for the tip. BTW, is there any way to use bare `Horse` in the imported file to avoid attaching `models.` to it each time?

Comment: Only if they are in the same package. But i see you are grouping your stuff by functionality (i.e. controllers go into package controllers, models into package models, etc.). Why not group by feature? So `Horse` and your horse controller are both in the package `horse`?

Comment: @Karlom: you can use `.` import name to bring all the identifiers into the same namespace, but don't do that -- it's generally accepted to be bad practice.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to forge the app into  a MVC pattern, but apparently it needs lots of plumbing...

Comment: @JimB is correct, there is a way. But don't use it.

Comment: @Karlom Even when you use a MVC pattern there is no reason to group by functionality instead of feature.

Comment: @Danilo, not sure how to follow your suggestion. When I use `horse` instead of both `controllers` and `models` I get  cannot find package "horseapp/horse" in any of ...$GOROOT...$GOPATH). So I guess you suggest each package to be a self contained MVC. right?

Comment: @Karlom: yes. Put your horse controller and your horse model in the same folder. Call the package horse. Do that for each feature you have. That way everything related to one feature is in the same folder/package.